# VB.Net Need some tips for using JavaScriptSerializer to Deserialize JSON string

Tags: json, vb.net

First question asked here, it is nice to be part of a coding community!

Currently I am retrieving a JSON string from an API and the response is as follows:

```
[{"playerId":37067559,"championId":78,"championLevel":5,"championPoints":93023,"lastPlayTime":1454133232000,"championPointsSinceLastLevel":71423,"championPointsUntilNextLevel":0},{"playerId":37067559,"championId":105,"championLevel":5,"championPoints":39025,"lastPlayTime":1454130615000,"championPointsSinceLastLevel":17425,"championPointsUntilNextLevel":0},{"playerId":37067559,"championId":81,"championLevel":5,"championPoints":37068,"lastPlayTime":1454273384000,"championPointsSinceLastLevel":15468,"championPointsUntilNextLevel":0}]
```

I set the string to be "response2"

```
Dim response2 As String = serviceRequest.DownloadString(New Uri(Mastery))
```

However in using the JavaScriptSerializer the code exits my console

```
Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim model As MyModel = jss.Deserialize(Of MyModel)(response2)
Console.Write(model.championId(0))

Console.ReadLine()
```

I set the model for the Deserializer aswell

```
Public Class MyModel
Public Property playerId() As String
Public Property championId() As String
Public Property championPoints() As String
Public Property lastPlayTime() As String
Public Property championPointsSinceLastLevel() As String
Public Property championPointsUntilNextLevel() As String
End Class
```

However on startup the console exits itself. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use model.championId(0) aswell, I assume to becuase there is more than one set of championId.

Comment: don't you need array of `MyModel` to hold the deserialized object? `Dim model() .....`

Comment: @bansi can you guide me into the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need array of `MyModel` to hold the serialized objects

Try this (comment in code):

```
Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
' use model() to hold aray of MyModel
Dim model() As MyModel = jss.Deserialize(Of MyModel())(response2)
'As model is now array of MyModel you should use model(0), model(1) etc...
Console.Write(model(0).championId())
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know how to setup the array, I appreciate the help!